# Unwanted underline shows up on my header's link when I move the mouse over it

Tags: html, css, header, underline, text-decorations

On my website my header is linked back to itself and works fine, but when I put my mouse over it, an unwanted underline shows up underneath it and I do not want that. I already set the header's text decoration to none so I am not sure how to fix this. My code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href= "Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;

        }

        .Header {
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .socialmedia {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            top: 35px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
            display: flex;
            /* add this */
            align-items: center;
            /* add this */
        }

        .preorder button {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }

        .footer {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .img-fluid{
            width: inherit;
            height: 782px;
        }

        .mySlides~.mySlides {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            transition: 0.7s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center; padding-top: 20px">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <a class = "Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = preorder>
            <button style = "background-color: white;">Pre-Order</button>

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add text-decoration: none; to the anchor tag in your css.

Comment: You want to change the css that affects links at a default status (if any of your css does that), from "name", to "name:link". Also, the order is "LoVe For HAte". So: a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover, a:active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inspect anchor text decoration is located in a:hover , so add

```
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your CSS styles before the HTML. Best place is inside one single style block at the top of your HTML. Your style tag currently is below the link and that's why it's not applied.

You can remove the underline on hover by styling the `:hover` state specifically. However note that it's not ideal for accessibility.

There are few other issues with your HTML and CSS. It's best practice to avoid inline styles inside of the HTML tags. And you've linked to your home page with a `file://` protocol, use `http://` as its a webpage. If you're linking to the default home page then you can just do `/Home.html` too.

You're missing the closing `</body></html>` tags also.

I've fixed those below as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href= "Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body { margin:0 }

        .Header {
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .socialmedia {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            top: 35px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
            display: flex;
            /* add this */
            align-items: center;
            /* add this */
        }

        .preorder button {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }

        .footer {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .img-fluid{
            width: inherit;
            height: 782px;
        }

        .mySlides~.mySlides {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            transition: 0.7s;
        }

        .Header a:hover { text-decoration:none }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center; padding-top: 20px">Lunation Boards</h1></a>

    </a>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <a class = "Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = preorder>
            <button style = "background-color: white;">Pre-Order</button>

        </a>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'A' for snippet :D

Answer (score 1):

There might be a CSS for hover specifically. try: `a:hover {text-decoration:none;}`

Answer (score 1):

This CSS is what's creating the underline, and it comes from bootstrap

```
a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #014c8c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You can overwrite it by adding this to your CSS

```
.Header a:hover, .Header a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either use:

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

or use an inline CSS to explicitly specify the `text-decoration` for that particular anchor element.

```
<a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" style="text-decoration: none;"><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center; padding-top: 20px">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
```

the snippet below uses the first suggestion as that would be better, however, the latter does work aswell.

**snippet**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href= "Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;

        }

        .Header {
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: right;
        }

        a:hover{
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        .socialmedia {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            top: 35px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
            display: flex;
            /* add this */
            align-items: center;
            /* add this */
        }

        .preorder button {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }

        .footer {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .img-fluid{
            width: inherit;
            height: 782px;
        }

        .mySlides~.mySlides {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            transition: 0.7s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html"><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center; padding-top: 20px">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
    </a>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <a class = "Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = preorder>
            <button style = "background-color: white;">Pre-Order</button>

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The a:hover css fixed it

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ousmane's answer:

You want to change the CSS that affects links at a default status (if any of your CSS does that), from "name", to "name:link" (this will matter if and when more pseudo selectors are added to links styles).

Also, the order for the pseudo selectors is:
"LoVe For HAte".
So:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover, a:active
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer to this question was to change the hover attribute of the anchor tag. I am answering my own question so that when someone else looks at this question they will know that this is the correct answer that should work.

```
a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the container was a `<a>` element and all the children had their own underline.

I just set `text-decoration: none;` on the a container.